# How to authenticate with password in terminal, with fprintd authentication enabled?

Tags: debian, pam, authentication, fingerprint

I enabled fingerprint authentication on my laptop running Debian 12 by following [this guide](https://forty.sh/posts/2021-02-19-enabling-fingerprint-authentication/):

```
$ doas apt install fprintd libpam-fprintd
$ fprintd-enroll -f right-middle-finger
$ fprintd-verify
$ doas pam-auth-update --enable fprintd
```

Now every time I need to authenticate in the terminal, I use the fingerprint:

```
username:~$ doas echo foo
Place your right middle finger on the fingerprint reader
foo
```

This is nice when I'm using my laptop undocked, when and I'm using external mouse and keyboard, I want to be able to authenticate with a password.

I noticed that if I just wait, the fingerprint authentication just times out, and then I can successfully authenticate via password:

```
username:~$ doas echo "foo"
Place your right middle finger on the fingerprint reader
Verification timed out
doas (username) password: 
foo
```

and same thing for failing the fingerprint authentication:

```
username:~$ doas echo "foo"
Place your right middle finger on the fingerprint reader
Failed to match fingerprint
doas (username) password: 
foo
```

How can I get the same effect immediately and without reaching to the fingerprint sensor?